# Why do I need to add slf4j as a dependency in my pom file to use itext7 API?

Tags: dependencies, slf4j, itext7

I'm using iText 7 kernel dependency in my pom file. But when I call any iText API I get the error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

To solve that, I need to add `slf4j` dependency in my pom file.

Why do I have to add a dependency that is used internally by itext in my pom file? Shouldn't be the responsibility of itext have slf4j as dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I wouldn't call it an error. This is information or warning, but certainly not an error.

Secondly, `slf4j-api` dependency is already on your classpath. It is a dependency of iText and it is automatically added in a transitive way when you have a dependency on iText. If you didn't have that dependency initially, you would actually get an error, something like `ClassNotFoundException`.

You don't have to add any dependencies. All the required ones are already resolved transitively when you add iText. You can just ignore this warning if you don't need logging and continue use iText as you wish.

What iText has as a dependency is a generic API for logging implementations and you are free to choose whether you want to have any logging information presented back to you (sometimes there is quite useful stuff there) or not. This generic API is de-facto a standard today. A user is free to choose which logger implementation he wants to use (logger suppressing, printing to console, writing to file etc etc). And it shouldn't be iText's responsibility to decide this for user of the library. These three lines of information that you see merely hint you that iText actually logs some information which might be useful to you and you can set up logger output if you want to.

Some of the common logger bindings are:

- slf4j-log4j12: binding for log4j version 1.2
- slf4j-jdk14: binding for java.util.logging
- slf4j-nop: binding for NOP (No OPeration)
- slf4j-simple: binding that prints to System.err
- slf4j-jcl: binding for Jakarta Commons Logging

You can find them all on [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j)